# struct with parentheses vs double parentheses in Rust

Tags: struct, rust

What is the difference between?

```
struct Test();

struct Test(());
```

I understand that a struct can have tuples (unnamed fields). However, I am not sure what does `(())` mean in such a case? That it's a struct with one element which is an empty tuple?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> it's a struct with one element which is an empty tuple?

That's exactly right.

Technically these are different types, but they carry exactly the same amount of information as each other; none.

There is really no purpose in having that argument, and you generally wouldn't create a type like `struct Test(())` except in a generic context. For example,

```
struct Test<T>(T);
```

where `T` ends up being `()` due to some other requirements.